# Change Navbar Color not Working

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

This is the code I have for the navbar in app/assets/views/elements:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <%= link_to "Pandora", defined?(root_path) ? root_path : "#", class: "navbar-brand" %>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <% if defined?(Devise) %>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Account <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Edit Account", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

But for some reason when I use this stylesheet to change the colors of the navbar, the only thing that changes is the font styling...

/app/assets/stylesheets

```
.navbar {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
color: #000;  /*Sets the text hover color on navbar*/
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active >   
 a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
color: white; /*BACKGROUND color for active*/
background-color: #030033;
}

  .navbar-default {
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    border-color: #030033;
}

  .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
   .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #262626;
   text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #66CCFF;  /*change color of links in drop down here*/
   }

 .nav > li > a:hover,
 .nav > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: silver; /*Change rollover cell color here*/
  }


  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
   color: white; /*Change active text color here*/
    }



.navbar-inverse {
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  border-color: #16a085;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #222222;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
}

.progress-bar-theme {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}
```

I don't know what it could be.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: try to add `!important` after the color.

Comment: in your stylesheets folder which file are these rules written in? also i believe you are using bootstrap css framework. in that case you must use exact class/id rules by inspecting the elements and copy pasting corresponding class/id and you try putting your custom css rules inside application.css as to be last in the compiled css file. also using !important rule extensively is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reinventing the wheel try to use this generator and get ready css:

http://work.smarchal.com/twbscolor/

The generated css should be put into overwrites file such as bootstrap_and_overrides.css and this file included last in the css manifest file (application.css).

`*= require bootstrap_and_overrides
    *= require_self
    */`

Comment: Try to put it in overwrites file after include of application.css.

Or require it last in your application.css:
...
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
 *= require_self
 */

Comment: Putting it in application.css fixes it.

Comment: @Pabi, good please accept the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Though, I suggest you instead of putting in directly in application.css, create a separate file bootstrap_and_overrides.css, and then "require" this file in the top section of the application.css. Like: require bootstrap_and_overrides

Comment: Would it be @import "assets/stylesheets/navbar.css"?

Comment: You can use @import in the css area, but the top section with "= require" statements is the proper way to include your css files into your project. The application.css file is called Manifest file. But, in general, it is your choice how you want to organize things in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Your can customize the navbar color using the following code:

```
 .navbar-default 
    {
      background-image: none;  
      background-color: #2196f3; 
      border-color: #1976d2;
    }
```

Here, `background-image:none;` is plays the role. If you miss the line it shows the navbar-default in default color (White).